# Thing in list about fors and loops

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a list with 32 rows and 129 columns
an example would be

```
list = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 25, 20, 5, 8, 75, 45, 5, 0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 5]
```

I need to get the standar deviation for each column.

```
standardev= []

for i in list

standardev = i[0]

print(standardev)

returns 0,0,0
```

but then I need i[1], i[2] in the standar deviation list variable. All the thing the for is doing is just one i[0] list. Any ideason how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The numpy library has the std function to calculate standard deviation. Use it as follows:

```
import numpy as np
standard_deviation = np.std(list[i]) // standard deviation of ith column in list
```